# Touchpad the works well with Raspbian

Tags: hardware, peripherals, compatibility

I'm looking for a USB track/touch/mouse-pad that is compatible and known to work well with with the Raspberry Pi running latest Raspbian image. Just the pad, no keyboard attached.

Any help/guidance/links appreciated

Tom

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used  [this](http://m.futureshop.ca/?lang=en#/catalog/productdetails.aspx?ajax=true&sku=10226923&lang=en-CA)  but it is a little on the expensive side . If you would like the support for touchpad,  remember that it is just a distro Debian so my guess would be any touchpads that work with any Linux Distro would work perfectly fine with Raspbian. [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/touch-pad-not-working-in-debian-7-wheezy-4175463678/) is a forum post where you will find the drivers you need IF they aren't found by itself. I have also used a Bluetooth touchpad (with a Bluetooth receiver) and it work perfectly fine. hope that helps! Cheers!